# CadQuery: Selecting an edge by index (Filleting specific edges)

Tags: python, cad, cadquery

I come from the engineering CAD world and I'm creating some designs in [CadQuery](https://github.com/CadQuery/cadquery). What I want to do is this (pseudocode):

```
edges = part.edges()
edges[n].fillet(r)
```

Or ideally have the ability to do something like this (though I can't find any methods for edge properties). Pseudocode:

```
edges = part.edges()
for edge in edges:
    if edge.length() > x:
        edge.fillet(a)
    else:
        edge.fillet(b)
```

This would be very useful when a design contains non-orthogonal faces. I understand that I can select edges with selectors, but I find them unnecessarily complicated and work best with orthogonal faces. FreeCAD lets you treat edges as a list.

I believe there might be a method to select the closest edge to a point, but I can't seem to track it down.

If someone can provide guidance that would be great -- thank you!

Bonus question: Is there a way to return coordinates of geometry as a list or vector? e.g.:

```
origin = cq.workplane.center().val
>> [x,y,z]
```

(or something like the above)

Comment: What library are you using? Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Hi Richard, I'm using CadQuery (added a hyperlink). I couldn't find a tag and it wouldn't let me create one because my account is too new, so I'm not quite sure what I should do.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you for clarifying; I just created the tag for you. Your question is the first with it! :)

Answer (score 3):

For the posterity. To select multiple edges eg. for chamfering you can use `newObject()` on `Workplane`. The argument is a list of edges (they have to be `cq.occ_impl.shapes.Edge` instances, NOT  `cq.Workplane` instances).

```py
import cadquery as cq

model = cq.Workplane().box(10, 10, 5)
edges = model.edges()

# edges.all() returns worplanes, we have to get underlying geometry
selected = list(map(lambda x: x.objects[0], edges.all()))

model_with_chamfer = model.newObject(selected).chamfer(1)
```

To get edge length you can do something like this:

```py
edge = model.edges().all()[0] # This select one 'random' edge
length = edge.objects[0].Length()
```

`edge.Length()` doesn't work since edge is `Workplane` instance, not geometry instance.

To get edges of certain length you can just create dict with edge geometry and length and filter it using builtin python's `filter()`. Here is a snippet of my implementation for chamfering short edges on topmost face:

```
top_edges = model.edges(">Z and #Z")

def get_length(edge):
    try:
        return edge.vals()[0].Length()
    except Exception:
        return 0.0

# Inside edges are shorter - filter only those
edge_len_list = list(map(
    lambda x: (x.objects[0], get_length(x)),
    top_edges.all()))
avg = mean([a for _, a in edge_len_list])
selected = filter(lambda x: x[1] < avg, edge_len_list)
selected = [e for e, _ in selected]

vertical_edges = model.edges("|Z").all()
selected.extend(vertical_edges)

model = model.newObject(selected)
model = model.chamfer(chamfer_size)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code, i hope this will be helpful.

```
import cadquery as cq

plane1 = cq.Workplane()

block = plane1.rect(10,12).extrude(10)

edges = block.edges("|Z")

filleted_block = edges.all()[0].fillet(0.5)

show(filleted_block)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
base = (
    cq.Workplane("XY").box(50,60,15)
    .faces(">Z")
    .rect(30,30,forConstruction=True)
    .vertices().rect(10,5).cutBlind(until=-10)
)

edges = base.edges("|Z").all()
edges.sort( key=(lambda x: x.val().Length() ))

for ed in edges[:-4]:
    base = base.union( ed.fillet(2))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to work with solids (and therefore `cq.occ_impl.shapes` directly) instead of the workplane, and then turn back to the workplane once the object has been champfered.
With this approach you can shorten @ItsNotFunny's answer, since you will avoid the use of custom edge length but use instead directly the built-in ones.

A short example:

```py
import cadquery as cq

box = cq.Solid.makeBox(3,4,5)

# here you can code the condition to accept an edge or not
# you can use .Length()->float or .Center()->cq.Vector
# selector = lambda edge: edge.Length() == 3
selector = lambda edge: edge.Center().Length > 5.5

# create a list containing all edges to fillet (or chamfer)
edge_selection = [edge for edge in box.Edges() if selector(edge)]

# apply fillet (or chamfer)
chamfered_box = box.chamfer(0.6, None, edge_selection)
filleted_box  = box.fillet(0.6, edge_selection)

# check
reset_show()
show_object(chamfered_box)
show_object(filleted_box.translate((0,0,6)))

# you can then go back to a workplane using
cq.workplane().add(filleted_box)
```